# php log in form with messages and date and time

Tags: php, forms, passwords

I am trying to create a php log in form. I want to just make a few adjustments but when i've tinkered with it, it stops working...

If you can't see from the code, I'm trying to create a (mock) log in form that asks for a username and password.

- I want any blank textbox to show a red message to the right of the textbox. (i have the red error message, but I can't get it to the left of the box)
- I want a sticky form that keeps either field if its filled in (again, I think I have this set up but don't think its working all the way)
- I would like a person who enters the username: **user** and the password: **abc123** to see a welcome message. If you don't use that username/password combo I want a message that says that they are not authorized. (This is what i really don't know how to do)
- I want this all in a redux (also think i have that working but not 100% sure)

Any help would be greatly apprecaited!!

And here is my code:

```
<?php

define('TITLE', 'LOG IN');

// CSS
print '<style type="text/css" media="screen">
.error { color: red; }
    </style>';

    // Checking
    if ( isset($_POST['submitted']) ) {

$problem = FALSE;

// Each value

if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $problem = TRUE;
    print '<p class="error">Please enter the username!</p>';
}

if (empty($_POST['password1'])) {
    $problem = TRUE;
    print '<p class="error">Please enter the password!</p>';
}


if (!$problem) { //No problem

    // Printing the log in message
    print '<p>Thank you for logging in!</p>';

    $_POST = array();

} else {

    print '<p class="error">No entry!</p>';

       }

    }

    ?>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">

    <p>"Username": <input type="text" name="username" size="20" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['username'])) { print htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']); } ?>" /></p>
    <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password1" size="20" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in" /></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
    </form>
```

Comment: This is just a learning exercise, right?

Comment: I'm teaching myself PHP and i'm currently trying to learn more about forms. I've built some before but i wanted to experiment with some new techniques.

Comment: I hope I don't hurt your feelings, but there's a number of issues going on here. Let me see if I can whip up a simple script that does what you're trying to do, as a demonstration.

Comment: feelings not hurt at all! Thats why i'm here! ... I learn so much better by seeing completed code and seeing how to do things right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here is a simple login that is not meant for real world usage. Please read the comments included in the code to see what I have to say about each. Doing logins is quite tricky for a number of reasons, so this example is not meant to demonstrate a real world working codebase, but a very simple username/password check.

The security issues associated with a more sophisticated use are perhaps beyond this answer, but the below code is the way I would interpret what you have posted above, without getting to detailed (to the point of possibly making it hard to understand the simplest steps occurring).

Let me know if you have any questions. To see the form in action, check:

http://jfcoder.com/test/simplelogin.php

Also, I use PHP's HEREDOC syntax instead of quoted strings for simplicity. To read more about this sometimes handy form, see

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.error {
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php 

// Note, in most cases you will set a SESSION variable
// of $_SESSION['loggedin'], which would require you to
// use session_start() before you access any session
// variables.

// Note, this defaults to false.
$loggedin = false;

// If I get an error, I will put it in this variable.
$error = '';

// If the username is provided, run the code. Otherwise,
// act as if the login form was not submitted. This makes
// a hidden `submitted` value superfluous, and guarantees
// your users at least provide a username.
if ($_POST['username']) {
    // NOTE!!! In mose cases, you're querying a database
    // for a username/password match. In PHP, this often 
    // means a MySQL query. DO NOT USE THE BELOW IF YOU
    // ARE DOING SO!!! This will allow what's called a
    // SQL injection. You MUST wash your data with something
    // like mysql_real_escape_string() for the $_POST
    // values (NEVER trust submitted data, always validate
    // and escape as necessary), or use the PHP PDO library.
    // In this example, though, I use a switch to check the
    // values for exact matches, which means I do not need 
    // to escape (and mysql_real_escape_string() requires
    // a database connection to use).
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // Here, I check if the username and password match.
    // This is, of course, hardcoded, but to match your 
    // attempt, I chose to keep the form, although you
    // rarely see this in use in the real world.    
    switch ($username) {
        // My one case. For each additional user, you
        // would need to add a new entry with password
        // check. And I set my error text according to
        // the result of the code.
        case 'user':
            if ($password === 'abc123') {
                $loggedin = true;
            } else {
                $error = 'Username/Password did not match.';
            }
            break;
        default:
            // Note, I don't give a descriptive error
            // here. If someone reports this error, I
            // know what may have gone wrong, but the
            // user is not told the username does not
            // exist.
            $error = 'Unknown error. Try again.';
    }
}

// I will only show the welcome message if the user has
// successfully logged in.
if ($loggedin === true) {
    echo <<<HTML
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<p>Thank you for logging in $username</p>
HTML;
} else {
    // If an error text is set, display that error.
    if ($error != '') {
        $error = "<h4>Login error</h4><p class='error'>$error</p>";
    }
    // Here's my form, only shown if the user has not
    // successfully logged in (note, this is only a one-
    // time check when the POST data is submitted; I
    // would need to use sessions to "remember" the requestor
    // had logged in across page accesses.
    echo <<<FORM
<h1>Login Form</h1>
<form action="simplelogin.php" method="POST">
$error
<p><label>Username: <input type="text" name="username"/></label></p>
<p><label>Password: <input type="password" name="password"/></label></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Login"/> <input type="reset"/></p>
</form>
FORM;
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow. @jared -- Thank you so much for doing that! I don't know if this makes me a bad programmer or not, but I can really only understand codes/programs once I see completed, working code. Maybe I'll get better the longer I code and the more i learn. Again, thanks so much!! You're amazing!

Comment: @Chris - No problem, the more you try to understand and review other code, the more you'll get it worked out. It took me some time before I could just bash out code and have it work and be reasonably secure. :) If you consider this the answer to your question, please click the outlined checkmark next to the answer and maybe upvote it as well. :)

Comment: Clicked the checkmark and tried to vote, but i'm new here so I guess that will take a while before i can! Thanks though!

Comment: @Chris - Yeah, it's been awhile since I was new, so I can't remember the rules on when you can vote. I do know you can only click the checkmark on one answer, but you can upvote as many as you want. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my full code. I pretty much rewrote the whole thing, so I appologize if the coding style differs too much:

```
<?php
// Output our CSS code
echo    '<style type="text/css" media="screen">
            .error
            {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>';

// Define our variable      
$problem = false;

// Check if the form has been submitted
if (isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
    // If either user or password are empty, we have a problem
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $problem = TRUE;
    }

    // If there is no problem, username is user, and password is abc123, we're good
    if (!$problem && $_POST['username']=='user' && $_POST['password']=='abc123') {

        // Print our login message
        echo 'Thank you for logging in!<br />';
    }
    // Ok, there's either a problem or the username or password is wrong, so no entry for them
    else
    {
        echo '<p class="error">No entry!</p>';
    }

}

    ?>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="20" value="<?php
        if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && !empty($_POST['username']))
        {
            echo $_POST['username'];
        } ?>" />
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && empty($_POST['username']))
        {
            echo '<span class="error">Please enter a username!</span>';
        }
    ?>
    <br />Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="20" value="<?php
        if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
        {
            echo $_POST['password'];
        } ?>" />
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && empty($_POST['password']))
        {
            echo '<span class="error">Please enter the password!</span>';
        }
    ?>
    <br /><input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    <br /><input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for your code as well... I really am trying to learn (imagine that!) so it is super helpful to see different codes!

Comment: Ok, not to be a pest, but I just have 2 questions. After looking at your code (and running it a couple of times) I was wondering if there is anyway that the input fields can go away after you submit? (That seems like it will be important in the future on other forms I build). My other question would be if the input fields do disappear, is there a way to have the 'enter a password/username' appear alone without the 'no entry' message appear on top? I know that doing those 2 extra elements would require the if loops to change, i'm just not sure which loops to change. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Late-ish reply: Make the input fields check if `$_POST['submitted]` is set (if it has been submitted before, it will be). Instead of outputting the form as HTML, have PHP echo it ONLY if it is NOT true (meaning it has not yet been submitted).